# How to loop textboxes inside of a groupbox then insert it on sql database with 1 column only?

Tags: vb.net

hello i want to make a program which is inside the groupbox there are lot's of textboxes and insert it on ms sql database .. my problem is i cant figure out how to loop textboxes like for example: Dim as i Integer = 1 .. textbox(i).text..so that if you loop it using "For i ".. it will control the textboxes from textbox1 to textbox10

```
dim cmd as new sqlcommand("insert daily (day)values(@day)",conn) 

For i = 0 To 3

Dim lab(i) As Label
i = i + 1
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", lab(i).Text)
GroupBox1.Controls.Add(lab(i))
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
cmd.Parameters.Clear()

Next
```

Comment: `For Each txtBox in YourGroupBox.Controls.OfType(TextBox) : DoSomething() : Next`?

Comment: Don't use `ExecuteNonQuery`. Use the loop suggested to add rows to a `DataTable`, then use a data adapter to save the entire contents in one go.

Comment: can you share some sample codes ?

Comment: Do you have nested groupboxes inside the groupbox? And is there a particular naming convention you followed for these textboxes so that you can identify the textboxes inside the groupbox from the rest?

Comment: eventually i made textboxes in order .. that's why i created a typeOf groupbox because inside of a group box you can control whats inside.. i am using for loop also enable to save it to database .. :) thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Let's go over your posted code first.

```
    'Good, declaring and initializing a Command, sending query and connection to constructor.
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert daily (day)values(@day)", conn)
    'OK, a For loop
    For i = 0 To 3
        'Declare a vaiable as an array with 1 element of type Label
        Dim lab(i) As Label
        'Increment your For loop counter???
        'This will make your loop skip numbers and iterations
        i = i + 1
        'Since your array is empty and only has one element available at index 0
        'This line will not work.
        'On the very first iteration i will now equal 1 which is already out of bounds for your array
        'Assuming you actually created a Label in this loop, how would it have anything
        'in the Text property before it was even visible
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", lab(i).Text)
        'Can't add a non existant control, you never created an instance of a Label (would need the New keyword)
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(lab(i))
        'Good, opening the connection at the last minute.
        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'Good, closing as soon as possible, but what if there was an error executing your command
        'your connection would not be closed!
        conn.Close()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Next
```

Now, base on comments by @Ahmed Abdelhameed and @jmcilhinney, we will create a `DataTable`, populating it with a For Each loop. Then send the data to the database with a `DataAdapter.Update`.

In this case we only provided an `.InsertCommand` to the `DataAdapter` because all the data in the `DataTable` are new rows. In most cases we would also provide an `UpdateCommand` and a `DeleteCommand`. These can be generated for you with by providing a `SelectCommand` and using a `CommandBuilder`.

Note: You must use the overload of the `.Parameters.Add` method that includes the database column name. This provides the mapping for the `DataAdapter`. Double check datatype, field size and column name in the database because I used guesses.

The reason for using a `DataAdapter` instead of `.ExecuteNonQuery` in a loop is to reduce round trips to the database. Since you said you have "lot's of textboxes" this should improve performance.

`Using...End` Using blocks ensure your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```vb
Private Sub BuildAndFillDataTable()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Day")
    For Each tb As TextBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        dr("Day") = tb.Text
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    BatchUpdate(dt)
End Sub

Private Sub BatchUpdate(dt As DataTable)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection String")
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into daily (day) values(@day)", cn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@day", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "day")
                da.InsertCommand = cmd
                da.Update(dt)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```